# Planet-timer "device" from 1970s or 1980s possibly by Edmund Scientific

Tags: observational-astronomy, planet

Many years ago (early 80s or late 70s), I bought a cardboard "device" which I think was called "Planet Timer" and I think was sold by Edmund Scientific. Does anyone have any information on this device? Google was unhelpful.

The device had concentric revolving circles around a fixed Sun at the center. By revolving the circles to the current time (via tables provided with the device), you could presumably see what constellation each planet was in. You could also use it to approximate planetary conjunctions.

The circles were equal distance from each other, so I'm pretty sure the device couldn't actually have worked, but I'm curious to see if I can find out more about it.

Note: this is not a "planisphere" device, which did work, and for which I can still find plenty of information.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up finding this on page 14 of the Edmund Scientific Holiday Sale catalog, with sale ending on December 31, 1983:

[image]

except that it's "Planetimer" (and not "Planet-timer"), catalog number H9454.

A 1200dpi image somewhat shows how it's supposed to work:

[image]

My original question was going to be: could this device have worked?

I would also appreciate any other information on this product (including a better scan, ideally of the product itself, if anyone still has one).

For reference, here is the page on which the ad appears and the cover of the catalog in which I found it:

[image]

[image]